# BDD: How to write step definitions for integration tests when the SUT has not been developed yet

Tags: user-interface, selenium, integration-testing, bdd

Ideally, using the outside-in development style of BDD, you have to write scenarios first with associated step definition. Then have it failed. Then write enough application code to have it passed.

My question is, in a real scenario, how is it possible to write step definitions of integration tests when there isn't any UI developed which can be used by selenium to implement page object on OR any application classes which can be used in the step definition to perform business logic layer or model testing.

Am I missing something here? I am new to BDD and this is really confusing. Please share your practical experience, no theories please.

**Edit:**
Example Scenario:
A client wants an e-commerce web app. Initially asks for the usual features such as:
Product Listing Gallery
A Shopping Cart
Checkout with various payment options
Email notifications

As per my understanding(which is probably wrong) of outside-in development process:

1) I would be writing scenarios specifications using Gherkin after analysis of above mentioned user stories
2) Then writing step definitions for these scenarios (How do I write them since there isn't any UI or application classes to use from)
3) I run these scenarios which fail
4) Then the developers write some application code which makes my scenarios pass
5) Then refactoring my step definition.

Comment: Please add an example scenario to your question, and I show you what (I think) you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your so called scenario description is just a draft about what features the application must contain. It should be something like this instead using the [gherkin syntax](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin):

```
Feature: Product Listing Gallery
  To be able to order 
  The Customers should be able to
  Browse a product list

  Scenario: Listing products without filters
    Given Susan is a Customer
    When Susan asks for a product list
      And does not give any filters
    Then she should get a list of products 
      But only products the store has in stock will be listed

  ...
```

So you can have many scenarios in your feature file, and each of them describes an use case. After you have written the use cases into these files, you can add step definitions.

This part of the story is similar to polymorphism. By polymorphism you define an interface, which describes the abstraction (what to do) and you have classes, which implement the interface in certain ways (how to do it). If you don't feel the analogy already: feature descriptions are about what to do, and step definitions are about how to do it. I think it is evident, that you can use many different kind of step definitions with the same feature description, just like many classes can implement the same interface by polymorphism. So you can write e2e test step definitions if you want to test the whole application. You can write GUI test step definitions and mocking out the business logic if you want to test the GUI in separation. You can write domain model test step definitions and mock out both the GUI and the persistence if you want to test the business logic in separation, and so on...

You can use all of these different step definitions with the same feature files. So if an implementation detail changes, e.g. you change GUI layout, then the only thing you have to modify are the step definitions which use the GUI and not the feature files, which contain only abstractions.

To answer the question, you don't need to develop outside-in. If you use BDD with DDD, then you can develop the domain model first and use the same feature files with different step definitions to develop the GUI later. If you want to start with the GUI, then you should mock out the business logic and test the GUI in separation first. After that you can write the step definitions for testing the business logic in separation. It is better this way than using e2e tests for developing the whole app, because e2e tests are slow. I don't support the latter approach, because I think it is better to think about the domain model without the influence of the GUI, database structure and other things. Ofc. these are just my impressions about how we should develop with BDD.